# Historical grammatically of “Do not go gentle into that good night”?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammaticality, poetry

I am not by any means a poetry expert, but I know a bit about grammar and writing. Ergo, I can say that in Dylan Thomas’s most famous poem, *[Do not go gentle into that good night](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/do-not-go-gentle-good-night),* the refrain that the poem takes its name from is ungrammatical. The grammatically correct way to write (or say) this would be “Do not go ***gently*** into that good night.” What I want to know is as follows:

a) Is there a historical usage of “gentle” as an adverb and b) if there isn’t, why did Thomas determine that it was okay to use an adjective adverbially? Or is there some poetry-grammar exception that I am unaware of?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81719/discussion-on-question-by-the-wordsmith-historical-grammatically-of-do-not-go-g).

Comment: Also, this is poetry where anything goes in order to fit the meter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of gentle as an adverb as well as and other possible non-standard usage of grammar in poetry are referred to as “poetic licence”.  As Collins  Dictionary notes:

> If someone such as a writer or film director uses [poetic licence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/poetic-licence), they break the usual rules of language or style, or they change the facts, in order to create a particular effect.